# Bundler Gemfile syntax highlight in Text Mate

Tags: textmate, ruby-on-rails, bundler

Hello I'm learning Rails3 so I start to use gem Bundler (http://github.com/carlhuda/bundler)
Does anybody know, how to setup TextMate to highlight **Gemfile** syntax?
Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In Textmate, select the Bundles menu => Bundles editor

Select languages instead of show all.

Select the Ruby on Rails language within the Ruby on rails bundle

Change this line:

```
fileTypes = ( 'rb', 'rxml', 'builder' );
```

to this:

```
fileTypes = ( 'rb', 'rxml', 'builder', 'Gemfile' );
```

Go to Bundles => Bundles Editior => Reload Bundles.

Reopen your Gemfile and you should now be getting the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Install the textmate bundle from https://github.com/drnic/Bundler.tmbundle.git.

Steps:
1. `mkdir -p ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles`
2. `cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles`
3. `git clone https://github.com/drnic/Bundler.tmbundle.git`
4. `osascript -e 'tell app "TextMate" to reload bundles'`
5. Open Gemfile and select "Bundler" from the menu below